# ArcGIS Server security settings via script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api

Can anyone point me to a method for setting a service, folder, or the site root security setting to public via script? It can be using one of the admin tools (e.g. server\tools\admin\manageservice.py), arcpy, powershell, batch file, etc.

I have Desktop, Engine, ArcObjects, and WPF runtime SDK installed on the server. This is on Windows o/s.

My motivation is to be able to script/automate the server install and setup process, including services. I want to keep it as simple as possible because simple is easy to implement and debug. So if there is a solution that doesn't use the server's REST/SOAP interfaces, I would prefer to try that first.

However, I will consider REST if that is the best solution.

Comment: do you have desktop, engine, or arcobjects installed on the server?

Comment: Yes. All of those plus the runtime SDK for WPF.

Comment: please include that info in your original question (touch edit) and anything you have tried. Possibly insight into why not rest/soap.

Comment: Indeed, why not REST, since that's the purpose of the Admin interface.

Comment: I've made some improvements/clarification to the question. I will consider REST implementation if that is the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution, but I'm interested in seeing other responses if there is something better out there.

[Example: Apply service permissions from a text file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Example_Apply_service_permissions_from_a_text_file/01540000061v000000/)